# How to bypass Person Ancestor error in maximo using automation script

Tags: maximo

I'm working on automation script where I need to bypass the person ancestor error in maximo, the data will come from xml payload. I just want to know if it's possible to bypass person ancestor error using automation script?

I try to use erData.removeCurrentData it works but the downside is if the user wants to update the person record it will not possible because the removeCurrentData() method is removing all the content of the xml. It can Bypass the person ancestor issue but it will not be possible to update the other person record fields.

Comment: PersonAncestor is essentially the cached and directly query-able results of a hierarchical query on `person.personid` and `person.supervisor`. If you bypass PersonAncestor errors, you will likely cause data integrity issues. You will also reduce the usefulness of the Person implementation of the Ancestor pattern -- a pattern that is common in Maximo.